# Signature over printed name

Tags: letters

I am writing a letter using `newlfm`, which implements the typeset signature with this code:

```
\namefrom{\textbf{Juan de la Cruz}\\
          "Expert" TeXnician\\
          Telephone: \printphonefrom\\
          E-mail: \printemailfrom}
```

How do I add my (scanned) signature over my printed name? I want it to look like it was actually signed by hand. I wouldn't want to use `jpg` because it doesn't support transparency. Probably `png` or other format with transparency.

I might as well print it, sign it, then scan it back; but then everything will be treated as graphics (e.g. text can't be selected).

Comment: What Tex/Latex engine are you using?  Do you have a PDF or DVI backend?

Comment: You could consider scanning your signature and trace it in a vector drawing program. http://inkscape.org is one that comes to my mind, I don't know if it can export to something useful though. But when you've got vector graphics, you can easily achieve what you want.

Comment: @Charles, when I press Ctrl+T, pdflatex executes. Does this mean I'm using a PDF backend? I don't know much about backends yet.

Comment: yes, pdflatex *is* the pdf backend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a starting point:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\signature}
  {\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics{signature}}}}
```

Put `\signature` right in front of your name. I haven't tested this with `newflm`. If it's moving the argument around, you may need to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.
You may also need to add some scaling argument(s) to the `\includegraphics`, and adjust the first argument to `\raisebox`.

Definitely use png for this, if you are using a pdf backend. If you want transparency, think you get the best result by using the scanned signature as a mask on an all black picture. In other words, the scanned signature becomes the alpha channel of a graphic that has all its pixels black. Or blue, if you prefer. Otherwise, you tend to get a light coloured fringe around the lines of the signature. This is not too hard to achieve with gimp or ImageMagick. Using the latter, here is a quick recipe (assume your scanned signature is black on white):

```
convert -negate -background blue -alpha Shape scanned.png signature.png
```

Comment: Just for the record to help others: At first I didn't realize that `\baselineskip` was a dimension that can be replaced with lengths (e.g. 5pt, 1in, -25pt, etc). Excellent solution, @Harald! Thanks!