# Figure caption as name for digital signature

Tags: captions, letters

I use a image as my signature in a letter and I want my name directly underneath it.

so far, I have successfully changed the Figure caption by using

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{}%To avouid Figure or Fig
```

Which results in :

[image: 1]

Question: How can I align it directly below the image and avoid the "1:" and just have my name.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5359/27833

Comment: So you are putting the signature in a `figure` float. Why not just follow the directions in [Adding a signature on an online job application](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764). There's no need for floats here, unless it serves a specific purpose in your document.

Comment: @Werner Tjat's the second question I was looking for.  Thanks :)