# Signature over printed name in a `moderncv` letter

Tags: graphics, moderncv, overlays, letters, signatures

When trying to get the signature (**transparent** PNG) properly placed using the following code:

```
\name{Andrés}{BC}
\closing{\color{red}Atentamente,\\ \vspace{-10pt}\parbox{120pt}%
{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{transpSign.PNG}}\vspace{-45pt}}
```

in the head and `\makeletterclosing` in the document, I get the following *z order* in the output PDF (the signature here is printed *over* the "Ate**n**tamente," but *under* the "Andr**é**s...". I would like it to be ***over*** every typed text):

[image: Output]

As it seems I get the *z order* given by the code order, is there any way to force the desired *z order* but using `\name`, `\closing` and `\makeletterclosing`? The use of these commands doesn't allow fixing it by writing things in the desired *z order* plus some negative space to position the signature, or something like the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5340/signature-over-printed-name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER**

Upon comment from the OP, it became more clear that the OP desired to have a transparent signature image **overlay** the page text.  The problem with my original solution was that the image was laid down prior to the name, and thus underlaid the name.

Attempting to make the signature a `\stackon` overlay to the name also did not work, because the name shows up not only in the letter salutation but also in the upper right of the `moderncv` document page.  Thus, the signature overlay also showed up in two places on the page.

Therefore, the solution here was to use my approach of [How can I make a perfect page grid that fits my page for measuring purposes in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229279/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-page-grid-that-fits-my-page-for-measuring-purposes-in-t/229821#229821), using `atbegshi` to overlay something on a page at absolute coordinates (unlike my similar answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831) using `everypage` which underlays something on a page at absolute coordinates).

My MWE does not use a transparent image, but that should not pose a complication.

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{3em}{4em}{}{}

\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBoxForeground{%
  \smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red!80}{#3}}}}}}


\begin{document}

\recipient{Company Org}{Company\\Street\\City}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\name{Andres}{BC}
\closing{\color{red}Atentamente,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\makeletterclosing

\atxy{1.64in}{8.1in}{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=55pt]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION

It is not exactly clear how you would like things to appear, but here I use `\stackunder` to place the graphical image (signature?) under the `Atentamente` label.  One can play with the optional argument to `\stackunder` to specify the gap of the underset, depending on the height of your signature (which I manually specified as 25pt).

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{3em}{4em}{}{}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Company Org}{Company\\Street\\City}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\name{Andres}{BC}
\closing{\def\stackalignment{l}\color{red}\mbox{}\smash{%
  \stackunder[20pt]{Atentamente,}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,height=25pt]{example-image}}}}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also use classic style, but `\stackunder` produces an _undefined control sequence_ error. Thinking it better now, I don't think I explained myself very well in the question, as your image doesn't show that my problem has been solved. In the question I was talking of a signature **transparent** PNG which, in my image, is printed _over_ the "Ate**n**tamente," but _under_ the "Andr**é**s...". I would like it to be _**over**_ every typed text.

Comment: @Andrestand  First, `\stackunder` requires the use of the `stackengine` package.  As to the transparent image with overlap, I did not fully appreciate this aspect of the problem.  One would have to attach the stack to the last glyph printed, which would be your name, rather than the "Atentamente".  I will give more thought on how to do that.

Comment: @Andrestand Please see my revised answer.